# Intercourse during fasting n ramzan

Tags: sawm

My husband came to me after fajar prayer normally as he do n bite me on my cheeks i adkd him not to then he gripped me tightly and i felt like he is touching me with more intimacy so i askd him not to as we are fasting  then he touched me on private part so i again reminded him no its ramzan and kept on  interrupting him meanwhile but he penetrated ( i thought he was teasing me and will stop ) but he dint stop n penetrated , meanwhile i again asked him no dnt he said i havent discharged so its ok but then he asked me to check on google and then i told penetration means breaking of fast i know n google says the same  n then he continued n had discharge ( he assumed that its broken now so we can continue n i too thought the same but i wasnt agreed to break the fast with intercouse , my husband is always  annoyed when i disturb him during intercourse so i was afraid too . Lastly for sure i myself did not hav any  discharge.  inshort i want to know  what applies to me and i dint eat or drink during the day.i regretted it meanwhile as wel as later during the day as i wasnt willing to break my fast . Kindly tell what applies to me

Answer (score -1):

You must keep 60 days of fasting for having breaking your fast due to intercourse and these 60 fasts are not included in the fasts of Ramadan I think so